# Override US_export_policy and local_policy jar for a application

Tags: security, jvm, java, jce

Is it possible to override US_export_policy and  local_policy jar through JVM or application arguments?

Comment: Application is using larger keysize and i do not like to change default jar in jre\lib\security.

Comment: I've tried doing this with things like "-Djava.library.path=%PATH%:/opt/jce/", but no dice. :'(

My corresponding version of this question is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/623120/prevent-apt-from-overwriting-custom-files

Comment: @doc I think, I just backed up the default jar files and used unlimited strength policy files.  hth http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: My "answer" for this problem is available here: http://serverfault.com/questions/623120/prevent-apt-from-overwriting-custom-files/625224#625224

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. If you could do it programmatically, the entire idea behind export restriction of large-keysize encryption collapses.